# Is it possible to get other bot's uptime?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I just thought of this command and I am not entirely sure if this is possible or not. However, is it possible to know other bot's uptime besides mine? Through mentioning, providing its id, or getting it but its username.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get the bot uptime is through the client object. If you do not have access to the bot's source code you cannot get it's uptime - unfortunately.